# How to left-align items with each other in a grid that used justify-items: center

Tags: html, css

I am using `grid`. I centered my `items` but i want left position to be same on `cross axis`.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="img/featured.jpg">
  <div class="item2">Item 2 Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Note : i want solution in only grid. There is many temporary fixes for that but i don't want that because i am looking for a perfect standard grid alignment solution for it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it a few ways:

**1. Fixed Width Text (Not Responsive)**
Based on the information you gave in your question. you can simply set the width of the `item2` div to be the same as the image, e.g.:

```css
.box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    gap: 1rem;
    justify-items: center;
}
.item2,
img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
    <div class="item2">Item 2 Lorem</div>
</div>
```

**2. The Responsive Way**

This will allow us to  responsively set up the 2 separate alignments you require: *centre* the container element, and *left-align* its contents, e.g.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxcontent">
     Content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS: `.boxcontent { text-align: left; }`

**Why this works:**

You must have a defined relationship between the image and text, otherwise there is no way to tell the grid that these 2 individual elements must be positioned in relation to each other. You can do this by putting them in a container.

If you think about it, you are trying to do 2 separate alignments here:

1. make the image and text be **centred in relation to the grid** *but also*
2. make them be in **alignment with each other** so they are left aligned.

Putting them in a container achieves both of these objectives by creating a relationship between the image and text so that:

1. they act as a single unit in relation to the grid *and also*
2. allow them to be positioned in relation to each other regardless of the grid

**Working Example:**

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-items: center;
}

.boxcontent {
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxcontent">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
    <div class="item2">Item 2 Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had these 2 ideas in my mind... but its a temporary fix.. i didn't want any temporary fix.. it would be good you can provide any standard solution of grid for this... if there is not any standard solution for it then i will have to go with your way

Comment: @Curious If you have specific requirements, you need to include them in your question! We can only answer what we are asked :) But Option 2 is the standard way - if you think about it, you are trying to do 2 separate things here - (1) associate the image and text so they are in alignment with each other, and (2) make them align differently in relation to each other than they do to the grid (i.e. left aligned to each other, centre aligned in the grid. Putting them in a container creates the relationship so the grid knows to centre them together, and also align them to each other.

Comment: I think i will have to put in another div as  you are suggesting....

Comment: @Curious Yes, as I said this is the standard way to do it - I've updated my answer to explain a bit more. You must have a defined relationship between the image and text, otherwise there is no way to tell the browser that these 2 individual elements must be positioned in relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
} 

.item2 {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Hi dear">
    <div class="item2">Item 2 Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No its dynamic content. width may change according to content.

Comment: So image is dynamic or text is dynamic? Due to the provided style, image width is set to `200px` (static value.)

Comment: Can you give me more details for that?

Comment: text is dynamic

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was how to do this using the `grid` display

Comment: only grid layout you want?